# How to restart /dev/video

Tags: video, webcam, ffmpeg

I'm creating a webcam feed the following way:

- using this Python3 lib: https://github.com/Flashs/virtualvideo
- plus having `v4l2loopback-utils` installed (not 100% sure it's needed)
- enabling the video device with `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=2 exclusive_caps=1`

This gives a dummy feed on `/dev/video2`.

This works nicely a few times (I can select this webcam feed in video conf tools) however at some point I cannot initialize `/dev/video2` anymore. The error is:

```
Couldn't write image to ffmpeg, error output of ffmpeg:
ffmpeg version 6.0-6ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers

...

Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:0':

  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 221184 kb/s

  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 1280x720, 221184 kb/s, 10 tbr, 10 tbn

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))

[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55fea92ea8c0] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument

[out#0/video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55fea92ea780] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

[vost#0:0/rawvideo @ 0x55fea92eaf40] Error initializing output stream: 

Conversion failed!
```

This can be fixed by a reboot, however I wonder if there is a way to fix the video device without a reboot.

(Caveat: I don't know what I'm doing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to fix a `v4l2loopback` video device without a reboot:

1. Remove the device: `sudo rmmod v4l2loopback`
2. Readd the device: `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=2 exclusive_caps=1`

However I would recommend fixing the Python so that it either does not break or does reconfigure the video device back into a working state without resetting it.

Comment: That worked \o/ Thanks @Daniel T. I'll check the Python lib too if I can spot anything there.